# What components are necessary to have a functional data tier on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure

I want to set up a test case of my data tier on Azure.  For my scenario this means

1. putting a SQL Server database into Azure
2. Storing my custom .dll data access code
3. Creating a tcp listener to take XML requests, call the custom dll code, and return the resulting XML.

What is a way to accomplish this in the architecture of azure?

My current understanding is that I need to do the following for each step:

1. Create a VM that hosts an Azure SQL database
2. Make sure .Net is on the VM and load my .dll
3. Create a worker role on the VM.

So I'm thinking 1 VM, 1 database, and 1 worker role.  I have very little confidence that this covers my needs and I'm not sure what I might be missing.

It shouldn't matter, but our current client is a WPF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options on how to implement this.

For the database you could either start a VM from the Gallery with SQL Server pre-installed on it, and restore your database on it. Or, even better, create a Azure SQL Database, and create your database on that service. The difference:  Azure SQL Database is not a VM; it is a service. Chances are, your database should work as-is. But if it doesn't (for some reason), then you can fallback on a VM with SQL Server on it.

Regarding your DLL and website, you could spin up a regular Windows VM, and deploy your DLL and website on it; if you are doing a proof of concept, there may not be a need to have a third machine involved.  With that said, if your objective is to also learn about  cloud services (web roles for example), then yes, you could also deploy a web role separately, which you would need to configure to connect to your DLL through some sort of web service call. You can deploy your website manually by creating a package from Visual Studio, or push directly from within Visual Studio (both would require you to create a new kind of project - a Web Role project - and add your website to it).

If you deploy 2 VMs (a cloud service and a VM for your DLL), then you will also need to configure a Network (it's a specific service within Azure) so that your website can communicate to your service (where your DLL is installed).

Last but not least, you will need to create a storage account, in which your VM disks will be located. This storage account is also another service that is part of the Azure offering. Your disks will be stored as blobs.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back.  I'm really hoping to get more details on the order of creation as well.  The tutorials I find are a mixed bag and nothing really address anything beyond the most basic scenario.  Also they don't seem to link together and integrate very well.  Do you know any good links or have advice on how to set up something like this?  Also, to clarify my application is a desktop app.  I think we'll be focusing on Worker Roles and not Web Roles to avoid http.  (I'm drowning right now, but working my way to the surface).  Thanks.

Comment: I believe this MSDN article provides most of the steps you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460772.aspx

Comment: One of my points of confusion is the whole VM thing.  I thought I had to start with VM's, but apparently I don't.  I now have setup a full SQL Server Database (i believe it is NOT azure sql).  I did not have to create a VM first or anything.  Perhaps the database has it's own VM it spawned and runs off of, but I did not have to do it.  Also, my dashboard does not show any VM's or Storage components.  With this setup I was able to connect and upload my exisiting database using this tool, http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Comment: The VM is only necessary when running SQL Server. If you created an Azure SQL Database, then there are no VMs. So it looks like that's what you did since you see no VMs and no Storage Account. That's usually the better way to go. To confirm you have an Azure SQL Database, login to the Azure management portal (manage.windowsazure.com), and click on the SQL Database icon on the left. You should see your database listed.

Comment: My database is listed on the SQL Database icon display.  So, i guess it IS Azure SQL.  There is nothing that I see which states that on the information, so I'm glad you corrected me.  I've also set up a Worker Role which is running, but i have another stack question for the problems I'm facing with it.